# Complexity on nested for algorithm

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I'm currently studying to a Data Structure Course.
I need to justify what is the complexity of the following algorithm, but I don't understand how to solve it.

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++) 
   for(int j=0;j<i;j++) 
     for(int k=0;k<j;k++) 
        sum++;
```

Comment: Complexity is O(N^3) because you have 3 nested loops and they all depend in a linear manner to N.

Answer (score 1):

I will comment below every line so you can understand each complexity step.

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)          //C(N) + C(N) + C(N) -> 3C(N)
   for(int j=0;j<i;j++)       //C(N)(N) + C(N)(N) + C(N)(N) -> 3C(N^2)
     for(int k=0;k<j;k++)     //C(N)(N)(N) + C(N)(N)(N) + C(N)(N)(N) -> 3C(N^3) 
        sum++;                //C(N)(N)(N) -> C(N^3)
```

That gives you a complexity equation of 3(N) + 3(N^2) + 4(N^3) which results in **O(N^3)** because it is the most weighted variable in your equation.